# Meeting reminder in outlook

Tags: outlook

I've created a meeting request in Outlook and send it to 40 people. To date only 30 have responded with an answer.

Is it possible to send a reminder to those who haven't yet made a decision on attending the meeting? If possible I want to exclude sending it to those who already replied to the invitation(Regardless of whether they answered yes/no/maybe).

Thanks!

Comment: This might be better for superuser site.

Comment: Which programming language are you using to accomplish this?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should belong to superuser

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the Tracking tab, you can see who has responded. Deselect those that have responded, then select 'Message to Attendees.' It will only send to those that are selected. Be sure to NOT save the meeting request when you close, so your attending list is unaffected.